# What is the optimal order the tackle the rooms?

Tags: robot-vacuum-sim-2013

In [Robot Vacuum Simulator 2013](http://www.stolidus-simulations.com/robotvacuumsimulator2013/), what is the best order to tackle the rooms, in order to complete the game as quickly as possible?

[image]

Comment: This. Really. Exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My picture isn't perfect but I suspect starting with the right side of the start point in the living area and then working your way around the rooms clockwise (kitchen, washroom, bedroom) as below:

[image]

Some notes:

- watch out for the chairs (what a nightmare!)
- you can clip through the toilet